# Can't find Eclipse RCP bundle

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Please advise.
    What should I add to target platform in order to get such bundles available:

```
org.eclipse.fx.ui.workbench.fx
org.eclipse.fx.ui.theme
org.eclipse.fx.ui.di
org.eclipse.fx.ui.services
org.eclipse.e4.core.services
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.extensions
```

Answer (score 0):

`org.eclipse.e4.core.xxx` plugins are part of the core of Eclipse 4 - you can't add them to earlier version of Eclipse. If you are already running Eclipse 4 you should already have them.

`org.eclipse.fx.xxxx` plugins are part of [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) which supports JavaFX development.